# visual studio 2010/2012 setting to undef _WIN32 and define __GNUC__

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

This would be a very weird question, but is it possible to undef `_WIN32` and define `__GNUC__`, in visual studio 2010/2012 settings without touching any source codes?

I added `_WIN32` in "C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Undefine Preprocessor Definitions" (which is `/U"_WIN32"`), but looks like it is not honored by visual studio IDE.

The reason of doing this is to write linux/mac parts of code with the help of visual studio IDE and intellisense. Of course, this wouldn't compile, but as far as intellisense correctly parses and helps for `__GNUC__`, I'm ok. I just need autocomplete and other features.

Maybe someone wants to argue why I am using visual studio for linux? Well, all vcxproj/sln are already configured for windows, and I want to take advantage of it. So.. let's not discuss about other options, such as source insight, emacs tags, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor macro **_WIN32** is always define when using the microsoft compiler and it cannot be redefined/undefined (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I ran in to this problem as well and was able to get around the issue by doing the following in a globally included header.  One was already in play for me so I didn't have to deal with including the header everywhere.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#undef _WIN32
#endif
```